# How center button in layout

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a QPushbutton that is added to a layout. When I set the button is resizable, and increase the size of the window, the button becomes very big which I don't like. Is there a ratio option to set in the resizable option. So that, when I resize the window, the button gets resized but with a ratio not full. Also, I tried to solve this by using a fixed size, but The button doesn't get in the center of the layout, it' more look like to be added not in the center. Is there a better solution to make the button resizable, but with constrains, or with fixed size, but put in the center of the layout

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QWidget

class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.AddButton = QPushButton("Add")
        #self.AddButton.setFixedSize(80,30)
        #self.AddButton.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)

        self.vbox = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.AddButton)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 150)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to place it in the center of the layout then all you have to do is set the alignment:

```
def initUI(self):
    self.AddButton = QPushButton("Add")
    self.AddButton.setFixedSize(80,30)
    self.vbox = QVBoxLayout(self)
    self.vbox.addWidget(self.AddButton, alignment=Qt.AlignHCenter)

    self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 150)
```